# ActiveRecord accepts_nested_attributes and callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

classes

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :authors
  has_many :comments
  has_many :authors
end

class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :disabled
  belongs_to :post
  before_create :set_disabled

  def set_disabled
    if self.post.authors.first.name == "Foo"
      self.disabled == true
    end
  end
end
```

Creating a new post with nested attributes

```
params = {
  post: {
    title: "A New Post", 
    comments_attributes: [
      { body: "This is a great post" }
    ], 
    authors_attributes: [
      {name: "Foo"}
    ]
  }
}

a = Post.create(params)
```

We get an error in the `set_disabled` callback because the comment can't access the `post.authors` even though they're in memory.

Our current solution is to grab them out of `ObjectSpace`. There must be a better way to do this?

Comment: What exactly is the error you get? Something about your approach *(checking the relation in the `before_create`)* just **feels** wrong.

Comment: Also, does the same error *(whatever it is)* occur if you change the callback for `set_disabled` to an `after_create`? You'd need to call `save` on the model again, but I'm curious.

Comment: i didn't try using an `after_create`. All these need to be saved together. all or nothing. The error is that it can't call `nilClass` has no method `name`. `post.authors` is a blank array at this point, so that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you'll have better luck from the other side *(I can't test this at the moment)*, but what about trying this from the `Post` itself:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  # your associations ...

  before_create do
    comments.each do |c|
      c.disabled = true
    end if authors.first.name == "Foo"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your model need only slight change. Just add nested_attributes after associations

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  has_many :authors
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :authors

  attr_accessible :comments_attributes, :authors_attributes, :title .....

end
```

Comment: I didn't realize the order mattered. But my actual code actually has the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` after the associations. The `attr_accesssible` declarations are in the middle though. I will edit that and get back to you.